# Error: The default Firebase app does not exist

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm tryin to do a simple function about Reading Data Once. but I get error like this:

index.js

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var config = {
apiKey: "some api key",
authDomain: "fitto-exercise.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://fitto-exercise.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "fitto-exercise",
storageBucket: "fitto-exercise.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "some number"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

and the search.js is here:

```
var firebase = require('.');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("exercises/exercise");
ref.once("58.967", function(data) {
console.log("Got it!");
});
```

index.js and search.js in the same directory
I'm still inexperienced about this stuff maybe there are some noob mistakes.

This is my database looks like:[image: here]

Comment: To get started reading data from Cloud Firestore, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems here.  If you're trying to require() some other file, it needs to have an export defined.  In index.js (if that's what you're trying to require), doesn't have an export.

I'd suggest using just a single file for now, until you get your most basic code to work.

Also, according to the API documentation for [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once), the method accepts, as its first argument:

> One of the following strings: "value", "child_added", "child_changed",
>   "child_removed", or "child_moved."

"58.967" isn't one of them, and I don't know what you were intending to do there.  But you probably want to use "value" to get the value of a child in the database.

Comment: I've update my question with a pic, please take a look :)

by the way, I'm using cloud firestore instead of realtime database, should i change database URL?

Comment: Your code is using Realtime Database APIs.  It's not using Firestore at all.